# Could anyone tell me why my leapyears are not being called?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my program only outputs one result instead five?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063949/why-does-my-program-only-outputs-one-result-instead-five)

/*
 *Find if a year is leap or not
 */

```
public class LeapYear{

  public static void year(int leapYear){
    System.out.println(leapYear);
  }

public static void main (String[] args) {
 leapYear(2010);
 leapYear(2008);
 leapYear(2010);
 leapYear(2008);
 leapYear(1565);

String result;
if (year % 400 == 0) {
result = "is a leap year.";
} else if (year % 100 == 0) {
result = "is not a leap year.";
} else if (year % 4 == 0) {
result = "is a leap year.";
} else {
result = "is not a leap year.";
}
System.out.println(year + ": " + result);
}
}
```

why are all the leapYear() not calling?

Comment: Your code does not define a method `leapYear`, and does not define a variable `year`.

Comment: This is basically the same problem as your earlier question, which you accepted an answer to...

Comment: True tried it again and changed the code found the same problem, but i did mention that i was new to java

Comment: _Thinking in Java_ by _Bruce Eckel_ This is a book which you should read. It doesn't have to be necessary that book, but... I would say, read a book about programming and especially Object Oriented Programming. The problems you've got are so basic. And I'll say, I enjoyed the book.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't define any function named leapYear.

Answer (score 1):

`leapYear()` is not a function as defined above. `LeapYear.year()` is. If you change them, it will work :)